# Как происходит авторизация через api в php

Tags: php, api

Здравствуйте. Никогда ранее не сталкивался с написанием API для сайта. С получением общих данных вроде как разобрался.

Не понятен один нюанс: человек установил приложение. В приложении два поля : логин и пароль . Ввел и отправил .. Все окей, данные верны.

А что дальше должно происходить, чтобы попасть в ЛК: должны куки запоминаться на телефоне, сессии или что ?  Уже перечитал инфы и что-то не могу понять вообще.

Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно для авторизации в `API` используют механизм `OAuth2`. Суть в том, что ваш сервер при получении авторизационных данных должен отдавать клиенту шифрованный token, который в последствии клиент будет передавать с запросами в заголовках, по этому токену вы и будете определять клиент. Вот ссылка на пакет `OAuth2` сервера на чистом `PHP`. https://packagist.org/packages/league/oauth2-server
Так же если хотите вы можете воспользоваться механизмом `JWT` `Json Web Token` - тоже некоторая альтерантива OAuth2 тоже довольно популярная - логика такая же клиент посылает авторизационные данные вы выдаете ему JWT который в последствии он использует для обращения пока у тог оне пройдет срок годности. Вот популярный пакет про JWT 
https://packagist.org/packages/lcobucci/jwt
В общем случае особое внимание надо уделять механизму обновления токенов, когда они expire'ятся так как обычно `API` - приложение многопоточное, таким образом у вас может произойти ситуация когда два запроса придут один за одним с просроченным token'ом - и эт у ситуацию надо как-то решать.
В простом случае на update токена, если он уже идет должна быт ькакая-то блокировка и новый токен можно записать в БД со сроком истечения, в то же время заблокирвоанный запрос должен получить заголовок, требующий его обратится за token'ом снова и так пока не будет в базе доступен новый токен.(это как пример решения проблемы конкурентных запросов с просроченным токеном)

Comment: А в чем отличие логики передачи токена от использования простой сессии (передачи куки phpsessid)? Думаю вопрос где-то в безопастности, но вот где разница не пойму

Comment: Механизм протухания сессии не такой явный, как у токена, во-вторых cookie/session механизмы рассчитанные более на браузеры, так как там весь этот функционал работает из коробки, в других приложениях такое из коробки работать не будет. вот есть полезная ссылочка https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20222/oauth-access-token-vs-session-key?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: А токен хранится в телефоне пользователя и остается там даже после перезагрузки телефона, я правильно понял?

Comment: Токен хранится в storage на телефоне, до тех пор пока он не "протухнет". Токены обычно выдаются на ограниченный срок: 15 минут, час, сутки, неделя.

Comment: Токены валидны в течении этого срока, очень часто срок зашифрован внутри токена и проверить протух он или нет можно уже на этапе расшифровки - это точно верно для JWT, так как внутрь этого токена пишут определенные метаданные. Когда токен умирает при запросе клиентом(под клиентом имеется ввиду любое приложение - на телефоне, в браузера standalone js, desktop) вы выбираете одну из двух стратегий - молча обновить токен и отдать новый токен с новой датой истечения, либо попросить заново авторизоваться.

Comment: Можно скомбинировать эти стратегии - опираясь на дату последнего захода, если например токен кончился буквально 15-60 минут назад и клиент был онлайн, то можно обновить тихо, если не заходил неделю например - то можно попросить ввести пароль.